# Firebase database write permission rules using newValue and data to access existing data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, rules

I'm having a problem writing my rules in Firebase

My data structure looks like this:

```
"permisos": {
   "owners" : {
      "$userId" : {
          "$client" : true
       }
   }
 }
 "data" : {
    "promotions" : {
       "$promotion_key" : {
           "property1:" : "some value"
           "client" : "client name"
       }
    }
  }
```

I'm writing the rules to write under "data/promotions/$promotion_key. I would like to verify if a current user has permission to write the promotion entry with the corresponding property client value (insert, update o delete). So far i've tried the following rule:

```
".write" : "root.child('permisos').child('owners').child(auth.uid).child(newData.child('client').val()).exists() || "root.child('permisos').child('owners').child(auth.uid).child(data.child('client').val()).exists()"
```

The first part of the rule checks for an insert, the second part checks an attempt to delete.

According to the order of the OR clauses, i'm able to insert but fails (permission denied) when trying to delete or viceversa. It seems that it doesn't evaluate both parts of the ||.

I've already try each clause of the or individual and they work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newData` won't exist for deletes, so you will need to guard against that to avoid the first part of your rule failing:

```
(
  newData.exists() &&
  root.child('permisos').child('owners').child(auth.uid).child(newData.child('client').val()).exists()
) ||
root.child('permisos').child('owners').child(auth.uid).child(data.child('client').val()).exists()
```